# PHP stripos problem

Tags: php, string

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if(stripos($url,'cp.utorrent.com')===true)echo "cp";
else echo "welcome uctorrent ...";
?>
```

for http://cp.uctorrent.com and http://www.cp.uctorrent.com output should be

> cp

but its both cases its printing

```
welcome uctorrent...
```

Comment: Use `stristr()` instead of `stripos` to avoid the boolean probing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripos` returns the position of string, which will be an integer. And you are comparing it with `=== true`

So this condition will be false by comparing an integer and a boolean.

You should use this

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if(stripos($url,'cp.uctorrent.com')===FALSE)  // here in your code its cp.utorrent.com
   echo "welcome uctorrent ...";
else
   echo "cp";
```

Or

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if(stripos($url,'cp.uctorrent.com'))
    echo "cp";
else 
    echo "welcome uctorrent ...";
```

Comment: your code is not working too ... its printing cp at both condition.

Comment: in your code you are using `if(stripos($url,'cp.utorrent.com'))` but it should be `if(stripos($url,'cp.uctorrent.com'))`

Comment: your code is working but where is error in my code. i didn't understand.

Comment: you are using `cp.utorrent.com` in `if(stripos($url,'cp.utorrent.com'))`

Comment: ooo mine ... i am such an idiot ... i was comparing uctorrent with utorrent ... SPELL MISTAKE

Answer (score 2):

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

```
Returns the numeric position of the first occurrence
```

So you're getting a number, and you're checking it to be the same type and value as "true". As it is an int, not a boolean, this will always be false.

Don't you mean `!== false` there?

Comment: A -1? It might not be the best answer, but it is correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

`stripos` will never actually return boolean TRUE. It will return the index or boolean FALSE.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Answer (score 0):

[stripos](http://ru.php.net/stripos) returns integer, not boolean, when an occurrence is found

Comment: if(stripos($url,'cp.utorrent.com')>=0)echo "cp";
else echo "welcome uctorrent ...";  //output is always 'cp'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if(stripos($url,'cp.utorrent.com') === FALSE) {
   echo "welcome uctorrent ...";
} else { 
   echo "cp";
}
```

Some notes here:

- FALSE and TRUE are constants. It's a good habit to use all caps for constants.
- All code blocks must always have a starting and ending curly braces for readability.
- stripos is a long-standing pain, always check value with === FALSE

Comment: They're not really "constant" constants, as in http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php . They're boolean literals. I'd say that it is a good habit to us all caps for constants, there are 'flavors' of coding that would allow for `true` or even `True`. I don't see the need to capitalize (is that a word?) this. I do really agree with the staches though.

Comment: @Nanne, 4 thumbs up for that (Yes, I do work barefooted so I can tease my dog under the table while coding :D)